# Static files not working on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml, static-files

I'm using the following yaml configuration:

```
      application: xxxxxxxx
      version: 1
      runtime: python27
      api_version: 1
      threadsafe: true

      handlers:
      - url: /bootstrap
        static_dir: static/bootstrap

      - url: /fonts
        static_dir: static/fonts

      - url: /js
        static_dir: static/js

      - url: /images
        static_dir: static/images

      - url: /css
        static_dir: static/css

      - url: /favicon\.ico
        static_files: ./static/favicon.ico
        upload: ./static/favicon\.ico

      - url: /.*
        script: main.app

      libraries:
      - name: django
        version: "1.3"
```

And my folder structure is like this:

```
    \
    ....static
    ..........bootstrap
    ...................css
    ...................js
    ...................img
    ..........css
    ..........fonts
    ..........images
    ..........js
```

In the development environment it works fine (using latest version available), but when I deploy the app it doesn't. I know the filenames are case sensitive on gae, but I've already checked that.

What else can be wrong?

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: i think u can help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895800/yaml-configuration-file-for-php-runtime-enviornment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stupid it may seems but removing the project from GAE Launcher and adding it back again and re-deploy it solved the issue.