# yaml configuration file for php runtime enviornment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

i want to run simple html website using GAE.Please help me in writing the correct yaml configuration file for my application.When I tried to deploy this application it gives an error.However if i deploy app without new handlers i.e those are not populated by app.yaml automatically it works
File structure is as

```
css
images
js
index.html
..
```

and yaml file is as :

```
application: shimlachadwick
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: .*
  script: index.html
```

Comment: Hi Rohit. What is your exact problem? what have you tried? SO is not made to write your code for you but give you suggestions on how to fix your issues. What is the issue you encounter with this?

Comment: Also, if you say "there's an error", it would be very helpful to copy and paste the **exact** error text.  Error messages are useful: they often have more than one bit of information.

Answer (score 1):

A typical app.yaml that just does static content would be arranged like this: put the static content in a subdirectory, say "htdocs".  Then have a handler at the bottom as your "catch-all":

```
- url: /
  static_dir: htdocs
```

So altogether, I'd expect the following app.yaml:

```
application: shimlachadwick
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_dir: htdocs
```

Let's say that you wanted the root path "/" to map to a index.php file that generates dynamic content (and must not be inside htdocs).  Then that's a matter of adding an earlier entry that maps to that index.php file:

```
application: shimlachadwick
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /$
  script: index.php

- url: /
  static_dir: htdocs
```